# I can't open recovered guitar pro 5 files on my laptop

Tags: midi, virus

I recently recovered (MIDI) Guitar Pro 5 files from my formatted drive but I can't open them and play them at all; my computer tells me "Unknown File. Loading Aborted." Any suggestions? I really need theses files.

Comment: Sounds like the recovery was incomplete and the files are corrupted. Sorry.

Comment: Do they have proper extension used by Guitar Pro 5? If they're midi files, is it possible to run them via some player like (always in our memory) winamp or windows media player?